# How to get the cell header names with colspan property on dragstart event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I have table who has some rows and some of these columns has colspan property. Here I am trying to get the cells header names of all those cells who are under specific colspan, for a getting single cell header Name, I am able to do that but I have an issue when there is colspan and and in that colspan there is `<span></span>` tag and when I will drag this `<span></span>` inside colspan. I want to get cell header names of all cells who are under this colspan

 My HTML is as bellow:

```
<table id="example"><tr>
<td >Row1</td>
<td ></td>
<td class="displaymultipledata" colspan="2">
<span  class="multiple" draggable="true"></span>
</td>
<td ></td>
<td class="displaydata">
<span  class="booked" draggable="true"></span>
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >Row2</td>
<td ></td>
<td></td>
<td ></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script code I am using for a single cell header name:

```
$('.booked').on("dragstart", function (event) {      
        var dt = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        dt.setData('Text', $(this).attr('id'));   
        var roomName =  $(this).closest('td').parent('tr').find('td:eq(0)').text();          
        var index = $(this).closest('td').index();
        var headerText = $("table th").eq(index).text();
}
```

But I want to do same with colpsans,how can I do that?